# how to pass named parameters to where clause in stored procedure in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I tried in Postgres  9.3

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tsd(koakuupav date, kolkuupaev date)
  RETURNS TABLE (
isikukood int
) AS
$func$
select 1 where current_date between koakuupaev and kolkuupaev
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

but got error

```
ERROR:  column "koakuupaev" does not exist
```

In plpgsql it causes same error at run time:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tsd(koakuupav date, kolkuupaev date)
  RETURNS TABLE (
isikukood int
) AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY  select 1 where current_date between  koakuupaev and kolkuupaev;
end; $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql stable;

select * from f_tsd(current_date, current_date)
```

How to pass parameters to where clause in function in Postgres ?
According to docs named parameters must work.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? The ability to use a named parameter inside a SQL function was added in 9.2 if I'm not mistaken. If you are on an older version, you need to use $1 and $2. But in either case you need to change the data type of the returned table to `integer` or cast the `1` to a numeric value (I guess that's the problem with your second version)

Comment: I'm using 9.3. According to docs named parameters must work. I changed return type to integer but problem persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter name `koakuupav` is missing an `e` in `pav` in instead of `paev`

```
f_tsd(koakuupav date, kolkuupaev date)

between  koakuupaev and kolkuupaev
```